# In the Edit Post page how do I modify with jQuery the status select list?

Tags: jquery, post-status, post-editor

Here is my JS:

```
jQuery('#post_status option[value="draft"]').text('Approve');
```

I simply trying to modify the text inside the option element in the status select form element in the Edit Post page.

For some reason it does not work. I am using 'admin_footer' action to add the JS.

Maybe there is another way?

I also tried this:

```
jQuery('#post_status option[value="changes-required"]').prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: Have you tried typing that into the console to see if it does anything?  That might narrow down if the element you want exists when you are calling the script.

Answer (score 0):

Your first line works for me when I type it in the console of Chrome:

```
jQuery('#post_status option[value="draft"]').text('Approve');
```

so I assume your problem may be that the element you want might not be loaded yet from where you run your script.  Try wrapping it in this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    (function ($) { 

        $('#post_status option[value="draft"]').text('Approve');

    })(jQuery);
});
```

Comment: Still does not work.

Comment: Have you tried pasting jQuery('#post_status option[value="draft"]').text('Approve'); into the console after the page is loaded?

Comment: I have not. Let me try it out.